# Hamiltonian in real and reciprocal space

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, hamiltonian, crystals

I found that sometimes people mentioned that Hamiltonian in real space or Hamiltonian in reciprocal/$k$-space. I wonder what difference of Hamiltonian in real and reciprocal spaces are?

For example, the tight binding Hamiltonian for pristine graphene is written below.

$$H=-t\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} a_{i}^{\dagger}b_{j}+b_{j}^{\dagger}a_{i}$$

Is this Hamiltonian in real or reciprocal space?

Comment: what's the definition of $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 3):

The real space and reciprocal space issue arises from the creation and annihilation operators.

For the aforementioned Hamiltonian of pristine graphene, assuming $a$ and $b$ are the fermionic operators of the A and B sub-lattices respectively, and the sum is carried out over the neighboring lattice sites only, this constitutes a real space interpretation of the creation and annihilation operators.

You can take the Fourier series of these operators and rewrite the Hamiltonian. For example,
$$a_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \tilde a_k \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi jk}{N}\right)$$
$$b_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \tilde b_k \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi jk}{N}\right)$$
assuming there are N lattice sites.

Inversion of this gives
$$\tilde a_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_j a_j \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi jk}{N}\right)$$
$$\tilde b_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_j b_j \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi jk}{N}\right)$$

These operators give, in turn, the reciprocal space or k-space version of the Hamiltonian.

The above Hamiltonian can be rephrased as
$$H=-t\sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} \left(a_{i}^{\dagger}b_{j}+b_{j}^{\dagger}a_{i}\right)$$
$$=-t\sum_{i} \left(a_{i}^{\dagger}b_{i+1}+a_{i}^{\dagger}b_{i-1}+b_{i-1}^{\dagger}a_{i}+b_{i+1}^{\dagger}a_{i}\right)$$
$$=-t\sum_{p} \left(a_{p}^{\dagger}b_{p+1}+a_{p}^{\dagger}b_{p-1}+b_{p-1}^{\dagger}a_{p}+b_{p+1}^{\dagger}a_{p}\right)$$
$$=-t\sum_{p} \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \tilde a_k^{\dagger} \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi pk}{N}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k' \tilde b_{k'} \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi (p+1)k'}{N}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \tilde a_k^{\dagger} \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi pk}{N}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k' \tilde b_{k'} \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi (p-1)k'}{N}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k' \tilde b_{k'}^{\dagger} \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi (p-1)k'}{N}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \tilde a_k \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi pk}{N}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k' \tilde b_{k'}^{\dagger} \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi (p+1)k'}{N}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k \tilde a_k \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi pk}{N}\right)\right]$$
$$=-\frac{t}{N}\sum_{k, k'}\sum_{p} \left[ \tilde a_k^{\dagger} \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi pk}{N}\right) \tilde b_{k'} \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi (p+1)k'}{N}\right)+ \tilde a_k^{\dagger} \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi pk}{N}\right) \tilde b_{k'} \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi (p-1)k'}{N}\right)+ \tilde b_{k'}^{\dagger} \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi (p-1)k'}{N}\right) \tilde a_k \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi pk}{N}\right)+ \tilde b_{k'}^{\dagger} \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi (p+1)k'}{N}\right)  \tilde a_k \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi pk}{N}\right)\right]$$

Further using $\sum_{p} \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi p(k-k')}{N}\right) = N\delta_{kk'}$ , we get

$$H =-t\sum_{k}\left[ \tilde a_k^{\dagger}  \tilde b_k \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right) + \tilde a_k^{\dagger} \tilde b_k \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)  + \tilde b_k^{\dagger} \tilde a_k \exp\left(i\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)+ \tilde b_k^{\dagger} \tilde a_k \exp\left(-i\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right)\right]$$
$$\Rightarrow \boxed{H(k) =-2t \sum_{k} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{N}\right) \left[\tilde a_k^{\dagger}  \tilde b_k +  \tilde b_k^{\dagger} \tilde a_k\right]}$$

This is the Hamiltonian in reciprocal space. This actually helps to find the dispersion relation E-k for a Hamiltonian upon proper choice of basis. Here I assumed a monoatomic basis for each. But for graphene, you need a triangular lattice. If you change accordingly, you will get the proper results.

In general, the Hamiltonian is a property of the system in consideration. So, irrespective of space, the physics remains the same and hence the Hamiltonian in both spaces carries the same information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "assuming a and b are the fermionic and bosonic operators respectively" - uhhhh.... what? They are both fermionic.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yup. I must have been thinking of something else while typing that.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Thank you very much for the helpful answer.

If I write the matrix format of the Hamiltonian for the pristine graphene in the following way, I think that this Hamiltonian is in the reciprocal/k space. Am I correct?

\begin{equation*}
 H = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -\epsilon_{A} & -t(1+e^{-ika_{1}+e^{-ika_{2}}}) \\
  -t(1+e^{ika_{1}+e^{ika_{2}}}) & -\epsilon_{B}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

If so, how to write out the matrix format of the Hamiltonian in real space for the pristine graphene?

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Kieran Yeah, it will be of this form. But not this matrix exactly. You need to consider a 2D triangular lattice for that. You can search the net for that.

Comment: @Kieran And we usually don't write H in matrix form in real space. Since those eigenvalues don't actually have any significance.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Thank you very much for the explanation. I understand now.

Comment: @Kieran You're welcome. Cheers :-)